# Get td's value dynamically on click of a button

Tags: jquery

I need get the value from `<td id='itemCadaPreco'>` when I click on button with the id of 'btnRemover':.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6APAx/

```
<tr id='itemCada'>
    <td id='itemCadaId'>1</td>
    <td>descrição aqui</td>
    <td id='itemCadaQtd'>12</td>
    <td id='itemCadaPreco'>R$ 10,00</td>
    <td>R$ 12000,00</td>
    <td style='width: 15px;'><button id="btnRemover">X</button></td>
</tr>


$(function(){
    $("#btnRemover").click(function(){        
        alert($(this).closest("#itemCadaPreco").text());
    });
});
```

**Edit:**
Guys this will be generated dynamically on a loop and the id "itemCadaPreco" will repeat, so call id on click will not work, we need use something like 'closest' or something like that.
thanks!

Comment: `tr`s should be wrapped with `table` and `tbody` tags. As IDs are unique, you should use a simple ID selector instead of `closest` method, `closest` selects the closest parent, http://jsfiddle.net/Tzq3S/

Answer (score 2):

What you might want is

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnRemover").click(function(){        
        alert($(this).closest("tr").find('#itemCadaPreco').text());
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rpHap/1/)

I'm assuming it to be a listing table where the same `tr` structure is repeated, then we have a problem because you will have multiple elements with the same id. The `id` of an element should be unique in a page, so I would suggest you to change all the `id` attributes to `class`.

```
<table id="tblItemData">
    <tr class='itemCada'>
        <td class='itemCadaId'>1</td>
        <td>descrição aqui</td>
        <td class='itemCadaQtd'>12</td>
        <td class="itemCadaPreco">R$ 10,00</td>
        <td>R$ 12000,00</td>
        <td style='width: 15px;'><button class="btnRemover">X</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(function(){
    $('#tblItemData').on('click', '.btnRemover', function(){
        alert($(this).closest("tr").find('.itemCadaPreco').text());
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rpHap/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your rows inside `<table>` tags.

You only need to use `alert($("#itemCadaPreco").text());`

Please look this working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/vLAQj/

Comment: Is your answer different from undefined ?

Comment: @Santosh, please review the link on jsFiddle.

Comment: When I saw the question undefined hadn't written, so I tried to find the problem and posted when got the solution.

Comment: Hahaha, undefined is a confusing username, the first time I read your comment I thought you were asking about the message of the alert.